# Project is Xcode 6.3 compatible but I cannot run this on 7.3

Tags: xcode8, xcode7.3

[image]

This is the message I got when I tried to run my app in Xcoded 7.3. I worked with this app with version 8.0 a bit.

Swift version doesn't seem to have any problem, for it is still 2.3.

The project format setting is set to 6.3 so I think it's supposed to be run in 7.3 too but it doesn't.

[image]

Do I need to do some more things to get this run in 7.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards opened in Xcode 8 can't be opened up in Xcode 7 or 6.

If you go to your Main.storyboard inspector, you can change the format back to Xcode 7, like this:

[image]

When you do this, you'll get this warning in Xcode 8:

[image]

And yes, you can go from Xcode 8 back to Xcode 7 format, but you can't go back to Xcode 6 format from Xcode 8.  If you want to get back to Xcode 6, you might have to open Xcode 7 first and repeat the steps I showed above to change the "Builds For" format pop-down menu.

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for. Thank you!